# Gnuplot : Hide the window

Tags: c, gnuplot

I have this piece of code

```
int draw_cell_bary(char *filename, char *filenameOutput, int format){

char buff[500];
FILE *f;

char draw_name_file_pattern[] = "%s%s%s%s%s";
f = popen("gnuplot", "w");
//sprintf(buff, draw_name_file_pattern ,"plot '",filename,"' with lines,' \n set term postscript\n set output \"",filenameOutput,"\"\n replot\n");
switch(format){
    case 1:
        sprintf(buff, draw_name_file_pattern ,"plot '",filename,"' \n set terminal png\n set output \"",filenameOutput,"\"\n replot\n");
        break;

        sprintf(buff, draw_name_file_pattern ,"plot '",filename,"' \n set term postscript\n set output \"",filenameOutput,"\"\n replot\n");
    case 2:
        break;

}
fprintf(f,"%s", buff);
fflush(f);
pclose(f);

return 1;
}
```

This code works fine but when I use it to create a drawing, the window appears in a popup and is immediatly closed. 
I want that the window from gnuplot stays hidden and that the output is created without the user to see it.

I've found --noraise but I'm not sure if that's what I want.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `plot` command is first in the commands you are sending to gnuplot--since the default terminal hasn't been changed, gnuplot plots to the screen, then disappears.

If you move the `plot` command after you `set terminal ...; set output`, then the window won't appear and you won't need the `replot` command.